# can't add page background color

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my current project, I want to transparent nativescript's page.

```
 this.page.androidStatusBarBackground = new Color("#811D88");
 this.page.addCss("page {background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.575);}");
```

But it not working as expected. Instant of transparent page, it is showing page background color white.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

Thanks